# How can i draw an object(a sphere or a triangle) at a specific location(say 1.0,2.0,0.5) in opengl(android platform)

Tags: opengl-es

I am new to opengl(Android Platform). I want to draw an opengl object say a sphere at a specific loaction in 3D. How can i do it? After drawing it i want to rotate it on touch event.So How can i do these two things? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You use transformation matrices to do that.
You need three matrices to do what you want, an object matrix (giving it position and rotation), a camera matrix (giving camera position and orientation in space), and a projection matrix (that causes perspective, i.e. far things are small, large things are near).

In android, you do:

```
float[] model = new float[16];
float[] camera = new float[16];
float[] projection = new float[16];
// those are the "basic" matrices

float[] modelview = new float[16];
float[] mvp = new float[16];
// those are their products

float f_scene_rotation_x = 10, f_scene_rotation_y = 30;
Matrix.setIdentityM(camera, 0);
Matrix.translateM(camera, 0, 0, 0, -2.5f);
Matrix.rotateM(camera, 0, f_scene_rotation_y, 1, 0, 0);
Matrix.rotateM(camera, 0, f_scene_rotation_x, 0, 1, 0);
// set up a camera, orbitting the scene

Matrix.setIdentityM(model, 0);
Matrix.translateM(model, 0, 1, 2, 0.5f); // set your desired position for the object (1.0,2.0,0.5)
//Matrix.rotateM(model, 0, angle, axisX, axisY, axisZ); // can rotate you object by defined angle arround defined axis
// set up model matrix

int mWidth = 640, mHeight = 480; // display dimensions
perspective(projection, 0, 90, (float)mWidth / mHeight, .1f, 1000.0f);
// set up perspective projection

Matrix.multiplyMM(modelview, 0, camera, 0, model, 0); // modelview = camera * model
Matrix.multiplyMM(mvp, 0, projection, 0, modelview, 0); // mvp = projection * modelview
// fuse matrices together

GLES20.glUseProgram(xxx); // bind your shader
GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(yyy, 1, false, GLES20.GL_FALSE, mvp); // pass the final matrix to the shader
// xxx is your program object, yyy is location of the modelview-projection matrix uniform inside your vertex shader
```

The last two lines of code rely on you using OpenGL ES 2.0. If that's not the case, use glLoadMatrix() to load modelview and projection matrices separately (no need to calculate mvp). Do not use built-in OpenGL ES 1.0 glRotatef() / glTranslatef(), those only cause sadness and irritation.

Note the code above contains the perspective() function. I suspect it is somewhere in Android libraries, but you could also use:

```
public static void perspective(float[] matrix, int moffset, float f_fov, float f_aspect, float f_near, float f_far)
{
    float f_w, f_h;

    f_h = (float)(Math.tan(f_fov * Math.PI / 180 * .5f)) * f_near;
    f_w = f_h * f_aspect;
    // calc half width of frustum in x-y plane at z = f_near

    Matrix.frustumM(matrix, moffset, -f_w, f_w, -f_h, f_h, f_near, f_far);
    // set frustum
}
```

I hope this helps ...

Comment: You can use gluLookAt() method for easy positioning. GLU.gluLookAt(gl, 0, 0, 5, moveToX, moveToY, moveToZ, 0, 1, 0);

Comment: True. Though it is quite error prone. Also not sure if it does what the OP asked.